# mouse cursor moves but cannot click with 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, mouse, kde

I am on Kubuntu 20.04LTS. KDE Plasma 5.18.5

Today, I found that the mouse cursor moves but cannot click at all. Sometimes the wheel works (exchange desktops) but sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the mouse cursor is constantly shown as `I` beam style, sometimes it changes to arrow style and `I` beam style depending on where it is. Selecting on the Desktop by dragging the mouse never works. The keyboard always works.

After entering virtual desktop by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and exiting by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the mouse click starts working. But I have to perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> every time after booting my Kubuntu.

I removed `virtualbox-6.1` and checked if the issue got fixed, but that didn't fix it.

Is there anything I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: Not really an answer, but another workaround...
For me on ubuntustudio 20.04 I have to Ctrl-Alt-F1 to go to a console,
then login and 'sudo pkill lightdm' to kill the display manager,
then Ctrl-Alt-F7 to switch back to the GUI and login again.
Of course that kills all my windows, but the mouse click is restored.

Answer (score 13):

So far I found nothing to resolve the issue.

But once happening the issue,

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go to a virtual console.
2. And then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to return back to gui screen.
3. As a result mouse click back to effect.

Currently everytime when mouse click lost, I do above.

Comment: Worked for me. Would be nice to know why it's happening?